# How add UNDO to my text field in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I have a simple text editor with cut, paste and undo buttons. I have this for cut and paste but i don't how to create undo button?

```
var clipboardFmt:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
var initialPoint:Number = new Number();
var finalpoint:Number = new Number();
var clipBoard:String = new String();

cut_button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,cutText);
paste_button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, pastefromClipboard);

function cutText(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    clipBoard = txt.text.substring(txt.selectionBeginIndex,txt.selectionEndIndex);
    System.setClipboard(clipBoard);
    txt.replaceText(txt.selectionBeginIndex,txt.selectionEndIndex,"");
}

function pastefromClipboard(e:Event):void
{
    txt.replaceText(txt.selectionBeginIndex,txt.selectionEndIndex,clipBoard);
    finalpoint = initialPoint + clipBoard.length;
    txt.setSelection(initialPoint,finalpoint);
    txt.setTextFormat(clipboardFmt, initialPoint,finalpoint);
}

txt.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE,count);
function count(e:Event):void
{
    wn.text = countWords(txt.text);
    function countWords(input:String):int
    {
        return input.match(/[^\s]+/g).length;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store a copy of text-field text in a variable. Each time text-field's value is being changed but before the change is applied (the event is called `TextEvent.TEXT_INPUT`) save a copy of text-field value into this variable. When `undo` button is pressed set text-field value to a value stored in this variable.

This is the simplest solution which will allow you to undo only one step back. You can use an array instead of single variable in order to store several states of text-field which will allow you to undo several steps back.

Answer (score 0):

create an array based undo system. Don't use the clipboard it will not work.